# How to get value from OkObjectResult and Subscribe from Angular6?

Tags: angular, asp-net-core-spa-services

This is a quick question for you guys!

I got an IActionResult that returns an integer with the Ok result.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]PageEditModel value)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

                var model = Mapper.Map<PageEditModel, Page>(value);

                if (await _pageService.InsertAsync(model, _unitOfWork) > 0)
                    return Ok(new { id = model.Id });

                return Content("Cannot insert page");
            }
        }
```

And I got my Angular method that Post the PageEditModel:

```
onSubmit() {
      this._pageService.post(this.model)
        .subscribe(result => console.log(result),
          err => console.log("Oops, something happens in post page."),
          () => console.log("Post completed"));
  }
```

I want to get the integer from result. The integer isn't in the result.

[image]

Did you know why I can't see the id from the result?

Thanks

Comment: try to add type any to result. (result:any) => ..

Comment: Looks like you're using deprecated `@angular/http` package. Try `console.log(result.json())`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to my old question. I was and still using The Swagger/OpenAPI toolchain for .NET, Web API and TypeScript to generate the Angular service layer.

In some case, NSwag can't generate some appropriate objects because of IActionResult return type. In order to do so, we must add the SwaggerResponse with the corresponding status code like so:

```
[SwaggerResponse("200", typeof(object))]
[SwaggerResponse("403", typeof(string))]
public async Task<IActionResult> ...
```

Then regenerate the code with the tool and you're good to go!